# In Windows forms, my check boxes are always transparent in Windows 8 but not in 7 or XP

Tags: winforms, checkbox, windows-8, transparency

I'm pulling my hair out over this one.  I have a simple checkbox.  I'ts on top of a panel with a gradient bitmap.  In Windows 7 and XP it looks just like a checkbox.  In Windows 8
it is transparent and shows everything on the desktop through it.
There are tons of articles on how to make it transparent but not one that I could find to prevent this!
Does anyone have any ideas?  I've tried all the different backgrounds, nothing works in Win8.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very helpful. You have not stated what programming language you are using, nor given any (short!) code samples with which we can replicate the situation on our machines.

Comment: Hi,Sorry, using Visual Studio 2010 C#

Comment: As to code, there isn't any.  It's the graphical environment.